# Rust Macro count repetitions of nested match

Tags: matrix, rust, macros

To declare a matrix, I'm using a vector of length `w*h`, and implementing the `Index` trait, which does the necessary maths to find the correct value in the matrix. Now I'd like to define a macro which makes declaring and using matrices easier.

Below is the solution I came up with:

```rust
macro_rules! _count {
    () => (0usize);
    ( $x:tt $($xs:tt)* ) => (1usize + _count!($($xs)*));
}

macro_rules! _count_semicolon {
    ($([$($n:tt),+]);+) => {};
    ($($($n:tt),+);+) => { _count!(_count_semicolon!($([$($n),+]);+)) - 1 }
}

macro_rules! matrix {
    ($($($n:expr) +);+) => {{
        use std::rc::Rc;
        use crate::Matrix;
        
        let len = _count!($($($n)+)+);
        let lines = _count_semicolon!($($($n),+);+);
        
        Matrix {
            width: len / lines,
            height: lines,
            data: Rc::new(vec![$($($n as f64),+),+].into_boxed_slice()),
            transpose: false
        }
    }};
}
```

The intent is simple: Declare a matrix by writing a grid of numbers separated by whitespaces, and rows by semicolons between braces. The height is the number of semicolons + 1, and the width is the total number of elements (ie the length of the vector) / height. The total length is determined by placing all elements as arguments into the count macro. A similar approach is used to count the semicolons, except the elements delimited by semicolons are placed in square brackets, to be treated as a single argument. Since this doesn't work, I use another macro to rewrite this into an empty argument, and pass it to the count macro instead.

So far my implementation seems to work for the following cases:

```rust
matrix! [
  1 2 3 4 5;
  6 7 8 9 10
];
matrix! [
  1 2
  3 4
];
matrix! [
  5 6
  7 8
];
```

However not for the following. The widths and heights are 1 and 2, respectively. It correctly counts the length (3), but yields a height of 2, and since `3/2.floor() == 1`,

```rust
matrix![ 
  1 2 3
];
matrix![ 
  4 5 6
];
```

An explanation and/or fix would be highly appreciated

### Edit:

I received two very good answers while I was asleep. Both of which do exactly as advertised, and answer the question perfectly, however, since @BallpointBen's answer is just slightly more descriptive, will be the one I accept.

Thank you both for your assistance <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `$x:tt` in `( $x:tt $($xs:tt)* )` in `_count!` matches *any* token tree — including `_count_semicolon!`! In fact, `_count` treats it as two token trees, `_count_semicolon` and `!`. The expansion of `_count_semicolon!` happens after, not before, `_count` reads its tokens, and `_count!` simply... counts the (two) tokens in `_count_semicolon` `!` instead of leaving them in place to expand. (You can see this if you compile with Rust nightly and `#![feature(trace_macros)]`.)

Instead, the following works:

```
macro_rules! _count {
    () => (0usize);
    ( $x:tt $($xs:tt)* ) => (1usize + _count!($($xs)*));
}

macro_rules! _count_semicolon {
    ($($($n:expr),+);+) => { _count_semicolon_bracketed!($([$($n),+]);+) }
}

macro_rules! _count_semicolon_bracketed {
     ($($n:tt);+) => {_count!( $($n)+ )};
}
```

We've split `_count_semicolon` into two macros (to avoid recursion) and have gotten rid of the `-1`.

Now, we have the following expansions:

```rust
matrix!();
// ... becomes ...
{
    use std::rc::Rc;

    use crate::Matrix;
    let len = 0usize;
    let lines = 0usize;
    Matrix {
        width: len / lines,
        height: lines,
        data: Rc::new(($crate::vec::Vec::new()).into_boxed_slice()),
        transpose: false,
    }
}
```

```rust
matrix!(1 2 3);
// ... becomes ...
{
    use std::rc::Rc;

    use crate::Matrix;
    let len = 1usize + 1usize + 1usize + 0usize;
    let lines = 1usize + 0usize;
    Matrix {
        width: len / lines,
        height: lines,
        data: Rc::new(
            (<[_]>::into_vec(
                #[rustc_box]
                $crate::boxed::Box::new([(1 as f64), (2 as f64), (3 as f64)]),
            ))
            .into_boxed_slice(),
        ),
        transpose: false,
    }
}
```

```rust
matrix!(1 2 3; 4 5 6);
// ... becomes ...
{
    use std::rc::Rc;

    use crate::Matrix;
    let len = 1usize + 1usize + 1usize + 1usize + 1usize + 1usize + 0usize;
    let lines = 1usize + 1usize + 0usize;
    Matrix {
        width: len / lines,
        height: lines,
        data: Rc::new(
            (<[_]>::into_vec(
                #[rustc_box]
                $crate::boxed::Box::new([
                    (1 as f64),
                    (2 as f64),
                    (3 as f64),
                    (4 as f64),
                    (5 as f64),
                    (6 as f64),
                ]),
            ))
            .into_boxed_slice(),
        ),
        transpose: false,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the first method [from the counting section of the macro book](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/blk-counting.html) to implement counting, because it's a single line. It's also best to use internal macros so your macro is more hygienic.

```
macro_rules! matrix {
    (@replace_expr $_t:tt $sub:expr) => { $sub };
    (@count_tts $($tts:tt)*) => { 0usize $(+ matrix!(@replace_expr $tts 1usize))* };

    [ $($($n:expr) +);+ ] => {{
        // Count every element individually
        // Putting parens around ($n) makes `count_tts!`
        // treat it as a single token tree
        let len = matrix!(@count_tts $($( ($n) )*)*);
        // Count groups separated by semis
        // Putting parens around ($($n)*) makes `count_tts!`
        // treat each group as a single token tree
        let lines = matrix!(@count_tts $( ($($n)*) )*);

        $crate::Matrix {
            width: len / lines,
            height: lines,
            data: ::std::rc::Rc::new(vec![$($($n as f64),+),+].into_boxed_slice()),
            transpose: false
        }
    }};
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8959fc95b871992a57040de37e0e893)